# Changing vista file permissions programmatically

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, windows-vista, file-permissions

I want to add some files to `C:\windows\XXX` (windows protected folder, in Vista), under the "TrustedInstaller" for my application. I do not want to replace any file so no issues on Windows Resource(formerly file) protection.
I have the code to change "ownership" to the current logged in admin,  however, I'm don't have any clue how to set its file permissions programmatically. I'm using VC++/MFC for development.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I not 100% sure what you actually want (as do you want it to look like TrustedInstaller installed the files?) but look at this [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379283%28VS.85%29.aspx) of using SetNamedSecurityInfo. You generally need to constuct a Discretionary Access Control List (DACL) for your file, however you can "borrow" one off another file with the permissions you want to clone using GetNamedSecurityInfo as building a DACL from scratch is considerably more annoying.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it is to just use the system function to run icacls with whichever parameters you need. Note that it's found in cstdlib (#include <cstdlib>)

```
system("icacls <params>");
```